# Attempted import error: 'makeStyles' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I 'm working on a react typescript app and i try to import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles' and it gets me error `Attempted import error: 'makeStyles' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'.`
i installed these :

```
npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @types/material-ui
```

Comment: Be sure you use a **named import**. `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` ([documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#material-ui-styles))

Comment: @BrianThompson i run npm install @material-ui/styles and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: What does your actual import look like

Comment: I use this import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

Comment: You shouldn't be installing `@types/material-ui`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell how to fix this

Comment: All of the demos in the Material-UI documentation are available in Typescript (e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/gre7p?file=/demo.tsx) and they use `makeStyles` and don't have this problem.

Comment: I think you are using material ui beta version 5. Try installing version < 5.

Comment: I got the same error and by referring the [docs][1] it was mentioned that 

> @mui/styles (LEGACY) The legacy styling solution of MUI.

I did `npm install @mui/styles` and then 

    import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

This worked for me


  [1]: https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

Answer (score 12):

I recently encountered this problem. This problem occurs when using the latest versions of Material UI.
To solve you have to import makeStyles otherwise:

Old version :
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

New version :
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

For more informations : https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/

Comment: Not really a solution when you have npm modules depending on this. The guys in material ui really messed it up this time.

Answer (score 10):

This is how i solved it

```
npm install @mui/styles
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

Comment: This works with the new version of Material-Ui

Answer (score 5):

I  resolved the issue, The makeStyles JSS utility is no longer exported from `@material-ui/core/styles`. You can use `@material-ui/styles/makeStyles` instead. Make sure to add a ThemeProvider at the root of your application.

So in older versions `makeStyles` was import from '@material-ui/core/styles'

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

But in newer version import `makeStyles` from '@material-ui/core/styles'

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but I solved it by downgrading the ui-material version in package.json :

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2", (was 5xxxbeta)
 "@material-ui/icons":"^4.11.2", ((was 5xxxbeta)
```

After:
$ yarn install

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 5 of material ui, you need to import the below package;

1. @material-ui/lab
2. @material-ui/icons

Then import the makeStyles function from material ui

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue apply with **createTheme**. You will need to change from

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
                         to
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

especially when switching from v4 to v5

Answer (score 0):

if it Stills doe not work try this!! this
npm i @mui/styles --force
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

Comment: Use of force attribute should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use tss-react.

According to material-ui documentation:
"The API is similar to JSS makeStyles, but under the hood, it uses @emotion/react. It also features much better TypeScript support than v4's makeStyles." (https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/)
On the link you can find an example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32999136)